# Empty in define C?

Tags: c, lzo

Quick question about the following snippet:

```
#ifndef __LZO_MMODEL
#define __LZO_MMODEL            /*empty*/
#endif
```

In an empty define like this what does it represent?

It's used in like manner:

```
#define lzo_bytep               unsigned char __LZO_MMODEL *
#define lzo_charp               char __LZO_MMODEL *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those answers do not cover many other possible cases.

Another example.

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define SINLINE static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#else
#define SINLINE 
#endif
```

and then

```
SINLINE void myfunc()
{
   /* ... */
}
```

and if the `DEBUG` is defined function will not be inlined making it more debugger friendly.

There are many other use cases.

Comment: Maybe it's best to add this answer to the linked duplicate question instead.